# Deutsches Wort für »Main Theme« (Titelmusik eines Videospiels)

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Ich suche eine gute Übersetzung für den englischen Begriff *main theme.* Diese Bezeichnung findet man besonders im Internet häufig für die Titelmusik eines Films oder Videospiels; bspw. wäre [*Dragonborn*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xHRQL5R4Do) das *main theme* von *The Elder Srolls V: Skyrim*.

Bisher habe ich keine bessere Übersetzung als *Titelmusik* gefunden, und diese passt nicht wirklich, da der Begriff impliziert, dass das Stück nur während des Intros des Films bzw. im Startmenü des Spiels zu hören ist; das muss beim *main theme* nicht der Fall sein.

*Leitmotiv* bezeichnet auch etwas anderes, da damit auch der musikalische Topos eines bestimmten Charakters gemeint sein kann.

Comment: Ich verstehe unter "Titelmusik" nicht, dass es nur im Intro zu hören sein soll. Im Gegenteil: Im gegebenen Kontext finde ich den Begriff sogar als sehr gute Übersetzung.

Comment: Hm, allerdings hat man durch *Titel* auch immer diesen Bezug zur Titelsequenz / Startbildschirm u.Ä.; "Main Theme" finde ich da allgemeiner, da es halt mit *Main* einfach nur aussagt, dass es das Haupt-Musikstück (^auch so ein sprachlicher Krampf) des Spiels/Films ist, unabhängig davon, wo es eingesetzt wird ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das (musiktheoretische) Pendant zu *main theme* im Deutschen ist "Hauptthema", so wie auch *theme* dem musikalischen "**Thema**" entspricht.

Thema und **Motiv** unterscheiden sich insofern, als dass ein Thema für gewöhnlich "größer" ist als ein Motiv - etwa kann es aus mehreren Motiven bestehen. In kleineren Stücken (wie zB "Für Elise") fällt eine genaue Abgrenzung jedoch schwer, sodass man beide Begriffe verwenden kann (wie es im aktuellen Wikipedia-Artikel dazu der Fall ist).

Der Begriff **Titelmusik** impliziert zwar, dass ein Stück am Beginn gespielt wird, aber nicht notwendigerweise *nur* dort. Wenn also ein *main theme* auch während des Titels vorkommt, kann man es mit "Titelmusik" übersetzen.

Letztendlich hängt die Wahl vom Publikum ab - das Wort "Titelmusik" scheint mir alltagstauglicher zu sein, während seine musiktheoretischen Kollegen oben für ein entsprechendes Publikum womöglich die genauere Wahl darstellen.